# Не сохраняется значение из ActiveForm->dropdownlist в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть отдельная таблица с категориями. Данные извлекаются через

```
Category::find()->select(['title'])->indexBy('id')->column();
```

и передаются во View как переменная $categorylist.

Через print_r распечатывается, в принципе, как мапа

```
Array
(
    [0] => Категория 1
    [3] => Категория 3
)
```

В представлении с ActiveForm соответственно

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownList($categories) ?>
```

В HMTML у них есть нормальные value=0 и value=3. Однако при сохранении всегда идёт 0. По идее же должен сохраняться value? В БД всегда сохраняется 0.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ пока писал вопрос. Помогло добавление

```
[['category'], number],
```

в правила валидации. Теперь цифра сохраняется.